# Grunt serve, how to disable syntax code checking after change the code in file?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm using grunt serve to reload automatically website after the change in the code.

But my app is now quite large and i would like to speed up reloading of the page by disabling syntax checking.

Is it possible using Yeoman and Grunt and how can i do it ?

Comment: the main SO question: what did you try? gruntfile describes dependencies, so it is just a matter of changing them. you didn't provide any details so I can give you only generic advice: remove sytax-checking task from the list of dependencies of "serve" task

Answer (score 0):

You need to register or change the existing task from Gruntfile.js so you need something like :

```
grunt.task.registerTask('serve', [
        // other tasks you possibly wanna run like syntax - checking
        // remove everything also jshint
        'serve'
    ]);
```

by doing so only serve will run, anyhow you need to provide more info + code sample to get proper help, with the info you provided that's all you can get!